# Ratio and fraction, transfer of water from Container A to B.

Tags: fractions, ratio

The ratio of the capacity of Container A to the capacity of Container B was 4:1. 2/9 of Container A was filled with water. If all the water in Container A is poured into the empty Container B, what fraction of Container B would be filled with water?

Comment: What do you think? Please share your thoughts, as this is not a homework site.

Comment: Suppose the capacity of $A$ is $x$. What does that make the capacity of $B$? And how much water was transferred to $B$?

Answer (score 1):

I got the the answer through a tedious method, making container A into 36 parts and container B into 9 parts and ended up 8/9 as answer for Container B.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Well done. I don't see why you describe it as tedious. It looks short and simple to me :)